# Mockito Error : However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock

Tags: java, android, junit, mockito, android-mvp

Hello i try to use mockito, to verify user password if invalid i want to verify it show error message.

But i got this following error :

```
Wanted but not invoked:
loginView.showPasswordError();
-> at android.fanjavaid.com.tdd_android_login.LoginActivityTest.invalidPassword_notLoggedIn_showPasswordError(LoginActivityTest.java:84)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
loginView.showEmailError();
-> at android.fanjavaid.com.tdd_android_login.presenter.LoginPresenterImpl.validateInput(LoginPresenterImpl.java:23)
```

Here is my test method :

```
@Test
public void invalidEmail_notLoggedIn_showEmailError() {
    LoginPresenter presenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(loginView, validator);
    presenter.validateInput(user);

    verify(loginView).showEmailError();
}

@Test
public void invalidPassword_notLoggedIn_showPasswordError() {
    when(user.getEmailAddress()).thenReturn("fanjavaid@gmail.com");

    LoginPresenter presenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(loginView, validator);
    presenter.validateInput(user);

    verify(loginView).showPasswordError();
}
```

I already mock the email user in `invalidPassword_notLoggedIn_showPasswordError()` with valid input, but i still get that error message.

Here is my Presenter implementation :

```
@Override
public void validateInput(User user) {
    if (!validator.validateEmail(user.getEmailAddress())) {
        view.showEmailError();
    } else if (validator.validatePassword(user.getPassword())) {
        view.showPasswordError();
    }
}
```

What i am missing for?

Thank you

Comment: Can you debug and check the object *loginView* reference in the test method and the real method? if they are different then mockito is right for failing verification.

Comment: Glad you have an answer to your problem! To make it easier for answerers to know you've got it sorted, and for future readers to find your solution, please edit your solution out of the question and [into a self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) you can accept later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **✔ ANSWER**

After several minutes explore again, i found something interesting.
I forgot to add mock to one class. 
Below i mock some classes moreless like this :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Mock User user;
    @Mock LoginView loginView;
    @Mock MyValidator validator;

    LoginPresenter presenter;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        presenter = new LoginPresenterImpl(loginView, validator);
    }

...
```

You can see that i mock validator class.

I got the error because in `invalidPassword_notLoggedIn_showPasswordError()` method i didn't add mock value for email validation.

```
// Mock validation
when(validator.validateEmail(user.getEmailAddress())).thenReturn(true);
```

If i don't mock it, it will ask about `showEmailError()` but we just verify `showPasswordError()`

This cause my implementation using condition to check one by one, started from check email is valid or not, then password valid or not.
If email doesn't exists and return value from validator doesn't exists the error will occured.

So i need to mock email address as valid and mock validator to return true(valid email).

That's my explanation and hope can help anyone who try mockito.

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you verify different method of mocked dependency instead of the actual method due to silly mistake.

For example, mocked dependency `LoginView` has 2 methods `showEmailError()` and `showPasswordError()`.

If you do stubbing for `LoginView` by invoking `loginView.showEmailError(any())` but you are verifying invocation of `showPasswordError()` which wasn't invoked, then Mockito will throw this error. But `LoginView` was interacted once using incovation of `showEmailError()`